# python zip and AES encrypt the output using subprocess

Tags: python, shell, aes

I'm new to python and I would like to do a zip and having the output encrypted in AES via python using subprocess command.

The standard shell command I use is as below:

```
zip -9 - test.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -out test.ENC -pass pass:123456
```

I tried to use in in python like below:

```
import subprocess
compress = subprocess.Popen(['zip', '-9', 'test.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
subprocess.Popen(['openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md=sha256 -pass pass:123456 -out', stdin=compress.stdout], stdin=compress.stdout,)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
File "test.py", line 3
    subprocess.Popen(['openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md=sha256 -pass pass:123456 -out test.ENC', stdin=compress.stdout], stdin=compress.stdout,)
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you manage to get the arguments to Popen correct the first time, and wrong the second time?  The first argument is a *list* of strings giving the program you're calling and its arguments.  The second argument should be `stdin=compress.stdout`.  The `stdin=...` definitely should not be inside the array of arrguments.

Comment: It is not working even if I do: subprocess.Popen(['openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md=sha256 -pass pass:123456 -out'], stdin=compress.stdout,)

Comment: I managed to get it working like:                                                                     
`import subprocess
compress = subprocess.Popen(['zip', '-9', 'test.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(['openssl', 'enc', '-aes-256-cbc', '-md=sha256', '-pass', 'pass:123456'], stdin=compress.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` but now I'm getting                       
`bad decrypt
140073400914368:error:02012020:system library:fflush:Broken pipe:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:318:fflush()
140073400914368:error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:320:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

- In my version of openssl, there is no -aes-256-cbc.
- '-md=sha256' needs to be '-md', 'sha256'
- Did you mean to send the output of `openssl` to a pipe?

```
import subprocess
compressor = subprocess.Popen(
     ['zip', '-9', 'test.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(
        ['openssl', 'enc', '-aes-256-cfb', '-md', 'sha256', '-pass','pass:123456'],
        stdin=compressor.stdout)
```

Comment: It works well but it prints the encrypted output to the console. I want to save the output as a file so I did `['openssl', 'enc', '-aes-256-cfb', '-md', 'sha256', '-out', 'test.enc', '-pass','pass:123456']` but it stays stuck at the compression process `*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.`

Comment: If you want the result saved to a file, add something like `output = open("myfile", "wb")` at the beginning and add `stdout=output` to the second `Popen'.

Comment: Regarding the warning.  You're passing "123456" as the password using an encryption algorithm that requires a 256-bit key.  I'm not sure how the version of openssl you're using converts a 6-byte key to a 32-byte key, but it's warning you that it's not using a good key derivation algorithm.